# Import custom UIView in ViewController

Tags: swift, uiview, importerror

I am very new to swift language. Now I have implemented custom UIView in my project using swift 3. I would like to access that UIView from my viewController. I tried to import that custom UIView in my view controller as I usually do in objective c. using `import PinTitleView`. But it doesnt work. It is still showing "No such module PinTitleView". I have no idea to deal with this. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: you can simple use like this  var myView:CustomView!

Comment: You do not need an import statement in Swift.  If it is in the same project, you can just use it.

Comment: please read this tutorial https://medium.com/@brianclouser/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960

Comment: is pinTitleView in objective c or swift?

Comment: @IOSSingh if I write like this "var myView : PinTitleView!", It is showing error "Use of undeclared type 'PinTitleView'".

Comment: share some code which you tried?

Comment: @NyeinEiEiTun can you show your code?

Comment: _italic_ **bold** `public init(location: CLLocation?, title: UILabel) {
        self.title = title
       
        var myView = PinTitleView();
    }`

Comment: Actually, I am accessing my customview from the swift class under pod project. Can I do like that or Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @NyeinEiEiTun May be you first import that class then use it

Answer (score 0):

1. create XIB file
2. Create UIView Class SideView: UIView
3. select XIB file > select file Owner > select Identity Inspector
   set class Name
  4.

Use this code in UIView Class

```
class SideView: UIView {

    var view:UIView!

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "SideView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        return view
    }

    func xibSetup() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetup()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        xibSetup()
    }
}
```

5. declare variable

   var sideSubView:SideView!
6. Use Like This

   sideSubView = SideView(frame: CGRect(x: sender.frame.origin.x + sender.frame.size.width - 200 ,y: sender.frame.origin.y + 40,width: 200,height: 200))
               self.view.addSubview(sideSubView)